# What is the point of the body of the __iter__ method?

Tags: python, class, oop, iterator, python-3.4

What is the significance of the body of the `__iter__` method in a class definition in Python? 
It is my understanding that an `__iter__` method must return an iterator; then shouldn't every `__iter__` method only contain a return statement which returns an iterator (defined elsewhere) ? Why is there a body in the `__iter__` method in some cases?

Comment: Because the iterator to return may not be trivial to construct?

Comment: Even something as trivial as a return statement is a statement. Statements need to be defined in some context. It would be strange to invent a different type of thing when methods are already used for all sorts of object behaviors. Iterators can be completely different objects or could be used for meta programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very common for the `__iter__` method to itself be the iterator — in the form of a generator:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for datum in self.data:
        yield datum + 1
```

Which may of course be as complex as you desire.

There's only really one case where you end up with a one-line `__iter__`, and that's when you're wrapping a single other iterable and want to defer to it.  You could just as well ask about the "point" of `__getattr__` or `__contains__`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what you are meaning by body. I suppose you are talking about the definition of the method `__iter__`.

Well sometimes you could use `yield` to return a generator. In this case, you could write the generating logic in the body of `__iter__`.

Or returning another iterator might involve some logic. So it's not always simply a `return`.

Answer (score -1):

The **iter** method  returns an iterator or  defines a **getitem** method, taking sequential indexes starting from zero and raising an IndexError when the indexes are no longer valid.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question and isn't quite coherent.